# I am not receiving any error when i run my application but when a user registers he gets added to both client and worker tables. instead of one table

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Someone show me where my code is not correct. during registration, am having a user who is a client getting added to both client and worker tables, while a worker is getting added to both client and worker tables, which is not okay. Am not getting any traceback error when i run the app the duplication could mean that there is code which is running twice

signals.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.dispatch.dispatcher import receiver


from .models import  Worker,Client

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def client_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        group = Group.objects.get(name='Client')
        instance.groups.add(group)

        Client.objects.create(
            user=instance,
            name=instance.username,
            email=instance.email,

        )
        print('Profile created!')





@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def worker_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        
        Worker.objects.create(
            user=instance,
            name=instance.username,
            email=instance.email,
        )
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


# Create your models here.


class Client(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(default="profile1.png", null=True, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    



class Worker(models.Model):
    CATEGORY = (
        ('Plumber', 'Plumber'),
        ('Electrician', 'Electrician'),
        ('Cleaner', 'Cleaner'),
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(
        default="profile2.png", null=True, blank=True)
    area_of_operation = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=CATEGORY)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
def registerPage(request):

    form = CreateUserForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            
            

            messages.success(request, 'Account was created for ' + username)
            return redirect('login')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', context)

def workerRegister(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('plumber_home')
    else:

        form = CreateUserForm()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                user = form.save()
                username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')

                messages.success(
                    request, 'Account was created for ' + username)

                return redirect('worker_login')

    context = {'form': form, }
    return render(request, 'users/worker_register.html', context)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can i prevent duplicate signals? am having a user being assigned to both 'client' and 'worker' instead of one group respectively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70301191/how-can-i-prevent-duplicate-signals-am-having-a-user-being-assigned-to-both-cl)

Comment: You already ask this question yesterday and I gave you an answer, please respect other members work and reply to why the answer was not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You link both _profile() functions to the save signal so both will create an object

Comment: Thanks for the reply. could you show me a code snippet of how i can get it to work

Comment: Well, if I understand your code you want to register a user and in the same time automatically create the profile. But as long as you do not decide or let the customer decide if he is a client or a customer the profile cant be specific. So the first thing to do is to decide where in the registration flow the decision should be taken

Comment: @Razenstein he asked the same question 3 time, he only except a snippet from someone, since nobody want to do his work he keep on posting.